# How can I get some conductive polymer (silicone like), with 1 Ohm/cm resistance?

Tags: material-science

I'm looking for a silicone-like (flexible, stretchable) conductive polymer with 1 ohm/cm resistance. Does anyone happen to know where/how can I acquire some?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Did you do a google search? There are lots of companies selling these polymers. Call them, ask them for the material that you need. Many of these shops can make materials to your specifications.

Comment: I did. Most of the results regard papers and how to make them in a Lab. I want to order and then test if their suitability to my needs. Do you know any companies selling that kind of materials (1 ohm/cm flexible & stretchable silicone-like polymer)?

Comment: When I do a search for "conductive silicone", I am getting more than half a dozen hits for commercial product on the first page alone.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about procuring a particular material and not physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean "silicone-like", not "silicon-like". Recently, I was looking for a similar material ([Need an intermediate resistivity part/material](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68510/need-an-intermediate-resistivity-part-material) ), but eventually obtained doped silicon rods.

You have several options, depending on the required geometry and properties of the part. For example, there are so-called "intrinsically conducting polymers" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductive_polymer ). Or you can use something like microwave absorbers, for example, foams "loaded" with carbon (see, e.g., http://www.eccosorb.com/Collateral/Documents/English-US/Electrical%20Parameters/ls%20parameters.pdf ).